# Need for Speed: Most Wanted 2012 release controls

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

I have got a Quantum USB controller. I have set up all the controls but now when I am trying to change my controls it's saying "RELEASE ALL THE CONTROLS". There is no button/option to do this. Would someone be able to shed some light on this?

Comment: Release all controls?  As in, let go of all buttons, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this a problem for me too until last minute. now i solved it myself:-)
here you go with the soln.

start-->search typing "NFS"--> you will see a file "controls"-->open in notepad. clear the content save it empty. now you start your game. now the controls are reset. edit for your convinience. all set enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to touch on the previous answer. Even if you do delete the controls there could still be a problem of the screen mentioning error again. So just delete one control in the text box.

The format would be like Left button_D. Just erase the D and save it.

Now start the game and check the controls. It will allow you to change the controls without any error messages.